# Prevent Okta from authenticating user during OAuth 2.0 authorization redirect

Tags: oauth-2.0, salesforce, okta

I'm building an app that requires users to authenticate with Salesforce. However, the problem I'm encountering occurs when Okta (SSO) steps in to authenticate the user automatically. The user is authenticated and redirected to the Salesforce home page, rather than the OAuth callback redirect as configured in the connected app (and passed as query param).

This is happening between steps 3 and 4 on this diagram: [image]

Question: Is there a way I can prevent Okta from automatically authenticating a user on a page?

Answer (score 1):

Just wanted to circle back and post my answer.  It was simply the authorization server url.  Instead of directing a user to a specific Salesforce instance (i.e., "na17.salesforce.com"), use the Salesforce auth server (i.e., "login.salesforce.com").  This keeps Okta from identifying the specific subdomain and trying to authenticate.